# Calculate the perimeter of a shape specified with a cloud of points

Tags: matlab, spline

I have a shape which you can imagine as a lake in a field observed from the top (2D). I determined the border pixels of the shape after an image processing, so that I have the coordinates of each border point.

Now I want to calculate the perimeter of this shape. My problem is that I have the points not in following order that would give a closed loop, but unordered.

How can a problem like this be solved in Matlab? (including Curve-Fitting-Toolbox etc.)

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: That sounds impossible - there will be ambiguous cases. You will need to order your points. Unless you don't mind making a gross approximation in which case you could use a convex hull

Comment: Investigate *convex-hull* algorithms, especially so if convexity of the perimeter is a reasonable assumption or approximation.

Comment: Is the "lake" convex? In that case you could order the points according to `angle(x-mean(x)) + j1*(y-mean(y))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `regionprops` for this.

Turn your image into a binary image with 1 inside your 'lake' and 0 outside (which you should be easily able to do, as you mention you extracted the boundaries).

Then use:

```
props=regionprops(YourBinaryImage, 'Perimeter');
```

You can then access the perimeter as follows: `props.Perimeter`

Answer (score 0):

If you have set of 3D points with (x,y,z) coordinates, you may set z to zero and use the 2D (x,y) points to find the convex hull using [convhull](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) regardless of their order .